# c++ fprintf prints only first string

Tags: c++, printf

I tried with below code:

```
String hi = "hi";
String bye = "bye";
fprintf(fileout, "%d: %s, %s", 10, hi, bye); //fail 
fprintf(fileout, "%d: %s, %s", 10, "hi", "bye");//ok
```

however, this cannot write hi bye to the text file. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fprintf` and related functions are C functions.

You need a "C string", which is a null-terminated character array (`char *` or `char const *`), not a C++ string (`std::string`).

```
fprintf(fileout, "%d: %s, %s", 10, hi.c_str(), bye.c_str());
```

See [`fprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) and [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Though C++ code will typically use the [C++ I/O functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iolibrary/).

Comment: Though, do note that the `String` that manhon is using is likely not `std::string`. Note that the capitalization differs. manhon, check whether your `String` class has a member function similar to `std::string::c_str()` and try using that.

Comment: Yes, @c45207 makes a good point. Look for a function that returns `char *` (or `const char *` or `char const *`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally want to use `fprintf` and company in C++.

```
fileout << 10 << ": " << hi << ", " << bye;
```

Comment: I use fprintf becoz i am trying to write float numbers to file, some are round up to digit, some are round up to 2 decimal.

Comment: @manhon: Then you'll want to look up `std::setw` and `std::setprecision`.